# Alternative for didSelectRowAtIndexPath when UITableViewCells are UIResponders?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

The cells in my tableview are horizontal UIScrollViews, which I assume is the reason didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called. I have my resignFirstResponder call in that method.

Does anyone have an easy way for me to fix this? Is there an alternative to didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Or is there a way to get that method to fire?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve this little problem of mine, I came up with a quick method you can implement in your AppDelegate.

```
- (void)setFirstResponder:(UISearchBar *)setResponder{  
    responder = setResponder;   
}

- (void)unsetFirstResponder{        
    if(responder){
        [responder resignFirstResponder];
        responder = nil;
    }   
}
```

Then whenever you call the first responder

```
[(yourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setFirstResponder:yourResponderObject];
```

And whenever you resign the first responder

```
[(yourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] unsetFirstResponder];
```

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably still using cellForRowAtIndexPath and probably you have UIScrollView as subviews of the cell's contentView. Can you just call a method up the superview chain, i.e. `[self.superview method]`, `[self.superview.superview method]`? That should at least get you back to the UITableView object and if necessary you could identify your UIScrollViews by tag.

Comment: Actually, it's even simpler than that. But you gave me the idea. I just override touchesBegan on the UIView inside one of my UIScrollView pages and then go up the chain like you suggested. Thanks for the eye opener! Cheers.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't as simple as that. I came up with a pretty elegant solution though, thanks again.